# Xamarin ADAL login loading forever

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, xamarin, active-directory

I have little problem for my application.

Shortly, i wanted make a mobile application for a business, which can communicates a sharepoint online site in android/ios. I registered the Azure site for i can try ADAL login.*(and first, not to break things up in corporate azure)*
I tried follow the next article: [active-directory-xamarin-native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T9Mg.png)
I created the app registrations and the other stuffs. But run the app on device, The login page has loading forever. [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T9Mg.png)

Next line does not end:

```
authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                                  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Anybody can help with that problem?

Comment: The link for active-directory-xamarin-native is not correct. And please add more code for login in logic.